# About Cell and its electric feild?

Tags: forces

1.When we connect wire in a battery there is a electric field so current starts flowing?

2.Do electric field spreads everywhere except in wire?

3.Electric field starts from positive charge to negative charge?

4.So if we place a positive test charge near to battery(but not touching a wire or battery) will electric field from battery exert force on that test charge?

5.I heard battery don't create electric field until circuit is incomplete then how can charged oil on Millikan oil drop experiment  experiences force although there is air in between plates  ?

Comment: A charged battery always creates an electric field, whether current is flowing, or not. The electric field inside a wire without current is zero, but it's usually small but finite, when a current is flowing.

Answer (score 0):

Electric fields and electric currents are very different things a good comparison is like what moisture in the air is to a river if you think of it this way things will make more sense.

Comment: Electric field causes current , isn't it?

Comment: no its almost like 2 different states of matter eg water and steam they are mate up of the same thing but different

Comment: OK . In then in cell how current flows if there is no electric field ?  Electric field causes force  electron to move and flow of electron in a dirn means current isn't it?

Comment: the electrons in a cell or battery are not free when the battery is not part of a circuit they only become seperated and free to flow as a current when the circuit is complete, this is because by completeing the circuit you are allowing a reaction to take place which frees the electrons from there original atoms they are then atracted to atoms at the other end of the circuit creating a current